# What are the effects of using the Boomerang Ricochet feat on a Skiprock?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I was investigating thrower builds, and came upon two Ricochet abilities:

- A *Skiprock* (*Races of the Wild*, p. 165), when it hits its target, can *ricochet* to another target of the thrower's choice, adjacent to the original target, with a penalty of -2 on the second attack roll.
- The *Boomerang Ricochet* feat (*Races of Eberron*, p. 108) allows one to ricochet a Talenta or Xen'drik boomerang; same effects, with the addition that the second target is not vulnerable to *Sneak Attack* damage.

If one were to use the *Aptitude* weapon enhancement (*Tome of Battle*, p. 148) on the *Skiprock*, one could apply the benefits of the *Boomerang Ricochet* feat to the *Skiprock*...

... and then what?

Would the abilities overlap, allow a 3rd target, or allow 4 targets?

Comment: …Obviously using the most liberal reading of the magic weapon special ability *aptitude*, of course. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92694/8610).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 4 attacks

The skiprock causes two entirely separate attacks.

> makes a second attack roll for the 
>   skiprock against the new target, with an attack bonus 2 lower than that of the initial attack.

Each "initial attack" is eligible for boomerang ricochet thanks to the Aptitude property.

> If your initial attack hits, you immediately make a second attack roll at a -2 penalty against any target adjacent to the original target.

Keep in mind that the third attack (from the skiprock's property) must be within 5 feet of the very first attack, not within 5 feet of the second attack (from the boomerang ricochet). Each boomerang ricochet is contingent on the prior attack hitting. The third and fourth attack require first that the initial skiprock attack hits (as the third attack will never take place otherwise)

> If the skiprock hits the target, it ricochets to another target

Essentially this is the chain of attacks:

1. First skiprock attack
2. Boomerang ricochet (if 1 hits)
3. Second skiprock attack (if 1 hits)
4. Boomerang ricochet (if 3 hits)

Comment: A skiprock is not a dagger..?

Comment: @KRyan I must be misremembering. I'll fix